# jQuery - How do I bind events to hidden elements that will be shown later?

Tags: jquery

I am trying to attach 'click' events to all elements of a particular class. The problem is some of the elements are on a tab that is hidden (display: none) at the time that the event is bound. (.bind()). It seems that when these elements are shown the events are no longer bound.

```
$('a.someClass').bind('click', function(){
  alert("test");
});
```

The hidden elements do not appear to have a click event bound. If I select the hidden elements:

```
$('a.someClass:hidden').bind('click', function(){
  alert("test");
});
```

It seems the click event is not bound when these elements are no longer hidden. Has anyone experienced this? Is there a way to bind and event to elements irregardless of their display property?

Thanks

Comment: test your selector to make sure it is selecting the hidden elements.  Elements that are display:none can still have events bound to them.  try $('a.someClass:hidden').length and see what that returns to test if your selector is correct.

Comment: 'regardless' or 'irrespective'. Never 'irregardless' ;)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

**edit 2 years later**: As some people pointed out, the `Live` function is now deprecated (as you can also see at the top of the linked docs page). The right event handler name for the current version would be `On`. See Maxim's answer for a good example.

*Original answer:*
Have you tried using [Live()](http://api.jquery.com/live/)?

```
.live('click',function(){/* code */});
```

?

<sub>version note: `live` has been deprecated in jQuery 1.7 and it was removed in jQuery 1.9. This answer is only correct for jQuery versions older than jQuery 1.7</sub>

Comment: .live is now deprecated use .on or .delegate api.jquery.com/live

Answer (score 66):

As of jQuery 1.7, the [`.live()`](http://api.jquery.com/live/) method is deprecated.

You can now use the [`.on()`](http://api.jquery.com/on/) method. By attaching a delegated event to an element that is viewable in the HTML when the jQuery is run.

So if `a.someClass` is hidden when jQuery is run, you should attach a delegated event to the body, so it will run when there is a viewable `a.someClass` element in the future, for example:

```
$('body').on('click','input.a.someClass',function(){
  alert("test");
});
```

Comment: Let's say you call a template that renders an HTML block on the page that is initially hidden, and that block features some inline javascript (for itself), the above code does not get triggered, as it is within that hidden element. Is there a solution so that the inline javascript will also get triggered?

Comment: $(document).on() works fine too. Best answer and explanation so far.

Answer (score 7):

Use delegate (note this is after you unhide them):

```
$('body').delegate('.someClass', 'click', function (evt) {
    // do something here
});
```

Answer (score 4):

Use

```
$('parentelement').on('click','taget element',function(){

})
```

`parentelement` should be visible at page load

Answer (score 0):

According to the jquery documentation at http://api.jquery.com/live/

> Attach a handler to the event for all elements which match the current selector, now and in the future

Here is an example of how to use it:

```
<!DOCTYPE html> 
<html> 
<head> 
  <style> 
  p { background:yellow; font-weight:bold; cursor:pointer;  
          padding:5px; } 
  p.over { background: #ccc; } 
  span { color:red; } 
  </style> 
  <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.5.js"></script> 
</head> 
<body> 
  <p>Click me!</p> 

  <span></span> 
<script> 
    $("p").live("click", function(){ 
      $(this).after("<p>Another paragraph!</p>"); 
    }); 
</script> 

</body> 
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Times have changed, it would now be done using ".on"

`.on('click',function(){/* code */});`

Comment: Why are you repeating [Maxim McNair's answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/11050439/499214)?

Comment: At the time Maxim was using `.live()` instead of `.on()`. Check the changelogs.

Comment: Understood, thanks. You might still want to delete your answer now that it duplicates another one.

Comment: By whom? Maxim mentioned `on` before you did - and in a better way, even. Also remember the priority on Stack Overflow should be to provide information to others, not to rack up points.