# How can I make my jQuery function work with hidden elements when they are made visible

Tags: jquery

I have this function that works initially but when I change the page to display hidden elements the function doesn't work with those elements that were once hidden.

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {

$(".paragraph-div").hide();

$(".toggle-div").click(function() 
                     {
 if ($(this).next(".paragraph-div").is(":visible")) {
   $(this).next(".paragraph-div").hide();
   $(this).text("More Info");
 } else {
   $(this).next(".paragraph-div").show();
   $(this).text("Less Info");
 }
});

});
```

I have made a jsfiddle here: https://jsfiddle.net/6k0bshb6/44/

So whats happening is it only works on `.paragraph-div`'s that are initially visible on page load so when I show new paragraph divs (by filtering the table or using the show more rows button on my table) they are already open when they should be hidden and the click function doesn't work on them.

I'm quite new to jQuery and don't know the correct method to do this but I think it has something to do with `("document").ready` I think I need to change that but what do I change it to?

If you'd like to see the problem you will need user agent switcher and a popular mobile user agent string as im working on a mobile version of my site at http://mobilereactor.co.uk/shop/mobile-phones/apple-iphone-5s-32gb-space-grey-deals/

Comment: Remove the quotes around `"document"` :)

Comment: I don't see how this would work at all in the first place. The first parameter passed to a jQuery event function is the event object, not the jQuery object. You're using the first parameter (the event object) as if it were jQuery throughout this function.

Comment: @JohnDavidKievlan Read the documentation for [`.ready()`](https://api.jquery.com/ready/) and scroll down to "Aliasing the jQuery Namespace". It's valid.

Comment: @JohnDavidKievlan First and only parameter passed to jQuery pseudo ready event is jQuery itself

Comment: the syntax is not the problem guys it looks different to what you're used to because you have to use weird syntax for wordpress so it doesn't confuse jQuery with other scripting languages

Comment: Huh. I've used jQuery for years and never knew that. Guess I was wrong :)

Comment: @4castle You are right but still working even if called on any empty object. The only difference is that using it on any different object than `document`, it won't use ready promise internally

Answer (score 0):

I found an answer to this question [jQuery - How do I bind events to hidden elements that will be shown later?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5655565/jquery-how-do-i-bind-events-to-hidden-elements-that-will-be-shown-later)

I don't fully understand it - but it works!

My solution;

```
//toggle details open and close
$('body').on('click','.toggle-div',function() {
  if ($(this).next(".paragraph-div").is(":visible")) {
        $(this).next(".paragraph-div").hide();
        $(this).text("More Info");
  } else {
        $(this).next(".paragraph-div").show();
        $(this).text("Less Info");
 }
});
```